# Apex Testing - Best Practices

Tags: apex, unit-test

A general question asked from time to time on stack exchange is how to implement tests.

There are some general questions to ask:

**What are your testing best practices?**

Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: This [What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) help information suggests the test "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." that I'm not sure your question passes...

Comment: @KeithC This question can be used to answer other "standard" testing questions. Therefore my suggestion is to answer the standard questions only once...

Comment: Very useful if you can keep the scope limited but that will be hard to do.

Comment: @Christian, if you could self-answer this question, then I feel it would be much more appropriate to ask it. You'd then also know how to scope it and what you wanted to address.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific list of best practices, granted there's a bunch of rules that are common to most people but different orgs require different things. I think this is too open for SFSE but I think it'd make a great topic for discussion on the dev boards.

Comment: Further to that, "why is X (not) considered a best practice?" would potentially make for a suitable series of questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Focus on testing for results
2. Coverage of code but ONLY in relation to #1
3. Never ever do #2 without taking into account #1
4. If focus on #1 then #2 and 3 will take care of themselves.